# checking if the method of a webservice is connecting or not

Tags: c#, web-services, httpwebresponse

I have browsed answers for checking if a webservice is up and running or not but what if i am having couple of methods which users are accessing at other end and i am supposed to monitor if those methods are working or not continously in a scheduler? I dont want to check if the service is running but if the method is working or not.

---

I can send some sample values to these methods and check but is there any other simpler way to check this.

Comment: You mean like AppFabric or SCOM? ... http://blogs.iis.net/appfabric/archive/2011/03/11/appfabric-wcf-service-template-c.aspx

Comment: @nonnb Hmm sort of.But i dont want to change the code of each method to check it since all these are inside a dll. I cant change the code everytime i want to check a method.So it should be something external to the webservice. I should just make a call and check it.Thanks anyways that was a new idea. :)