# How I can check availability check for webservices for applications running in J2EE platforms?

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee

How I can check availability check for webservices for applications running in J2EE platforms? Infrastructure guys think in just URL check, but I think not is enough could be better call inside the webservice a "dummy code". What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options but i think to actually check, you can create a dummy method and keep calling it to check if it is up and running, even i had a similar situation to tackle. Best is to do the above else you can check with ping or httpWebResponse and HttpWebRequest. Refer to this article which was posted earlier :  [How to check if a web service is up and running without using ping?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10206951/1278315) and [checking if the method of a webservice is connecting or not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9923846/1278315)